# How to join two table in mongodb and push into array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

Here i am having two collection `Organizations` & `Groups` , my requirement is i want to check `oldOrgID` in Organizations table and i have to take `schoolCode` & `schoolName` and push into `mainData` upto i had completed,

Now my question is `Organizations` table i have to take `orgID` and i have to check in `Groups` table `otherIds.orgID`, if suppose match means i have to take the `name` in `Groups` table push in to `mainData`

> Organizations:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c11efebd9cb4d35f47d6bd0"),
    "orgID" : "5b6c82462fb9ca35444d0ba2",
    "name" : "The Punjab Public School",
    "oldOrgID" : "176348"
}
```

> Groups:

```
/* 1 createdAt:12/13/2018, 11:06:02 AM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c11efc2d9cb4d35f47d6bcf"),
    "groupID" : "2",
    "name" : "8 B",
    "otherIds" : {
        "orgID" : "ORG1"
    },
    "version" : NumberInt(1)
},

/* 2 createdAt:12/13/2018, 11:05:08 AM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c11ef8cd9cb4d35f47d6bce"),
    "groupID" : "1",
    "name" : "8 A",
    "otherIds" : {
        "orgID" : "ORG1"
    },
    "version" : NumberInt(1)
}
```

> My Code

```
 var mainData = {};
var schoolCode = 176348 ;

db.Organizations.find({"oldOrgID" : schoolCode})
// .limit(1)
// .skip(15)
.forEach(function(doc){
    var OrgID = doc.orgID;
    if(mainData[OrgID] === undefined )
    {
      mainData[OrgID] = {}; // org name undefined means we are making empty object here
    }  
     mainData[OrgID]['schoolCode']  = doc.oldOrgID;
     mainData[OrgID]['schoolName']  = doc.name;

});
mainData
```

> Getting Output

```
{
    "5b6c82462fb9ca35444d0ba2" : {
        "schoolCode" : "176348",
        "schoolName" : "The Punjab Public School"
    }
}
```

> Expected Output

```
{
    "5b6c82462fb9ca35444d0ba2" : {
        "schoolCode" : "176348",
        "schoolName" : "The Punjab Public School",
        "group-section" : 
                    [
                            {
                                "name" : "8 B"
                            },
                            {
                                "name" : "8 A"
                            }
                    ]
    }
}
```

> Aggregation code

```
    db.Organizations.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      oldOrgID: "176348"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Groups",
      localField: "orgID",
      foreignField: "otherIds.orgID",
      as: "group-section"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "group-section._id": 0,
      "group-section.groupID": 0,
      "group-section.otherIds": 0,
      "group-section.version": 0
    }
  }
])
```

> Output

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c11efebd9cb4d35f47d6bd0"),
    "orgID" : "5b6c82462fb9ca35444d0ba2",
    "name" : "The Punjab Public School",
    "oldOrgID" : "176348",
    "group-section" : [ ]
}
```

Comment: Can anyone update my code, because i am new in mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$lookup is one of the pipeline stage of aggregation query so you need to use the Mongo Aggregation query as:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      oldOrgID: "176348"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "other",
      localField: "orgID",
      foreignField: "otherIds.orgID",
      as: "group-section"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "group-section._id": 0,
      "group-section.groupID": 0,
      "group-section.otherIds": 0,
      "group-section.version": 0
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: `Organizations` = **orgID** & `Groups` = **otherIds.orgID**

Comment: I just updated the Mongo Query in my last answer. Please have a look, it might help you.

Comment: I have used your code but not working. i am getting `group-section` is empty array

Comment: I had updated my `Aggregation code` kindly verify and modify my code based on my expected answer

Comment: Check once the value of 'orgID' field, because from your provided data 'orgID' field is not matching. In the $lookup stage we are checking the condition like orgID value should be same in both the collections. If you got any record with the same value then it will return a result, otherwise, it will give an empty array of 'group-section'.

Comment: Like, consider orgID=ORG1 then Organizations collection documents must have the same orgID for comparison.

Comment: Ya, it is fine, last question `$project` you are seting `0` but my case n-number of fields are there,i can't set all fields `0`, try to set as `1`

Comment: I got my expected results, Thanks

Comment: As per your Expected Output, I removed that fields in $project state, you want you can remove that ($project stage) whole stage.
In $project stage 0/1 value Specifies the exclusion of a field so you can emit that stage if you want.

Comment: Good One! @MayuriSKulkarni

Answer (score 1):

You can try Aggregate Query and use the

### LOOKUP operation:

Read more: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

You can something like this:

```
db.Organizations.aggregate([{
   $lookup:
     {
       from: "Groups" // <collection to join>,
       localField: "oldOrgID"  // <field from the input documents>,
       foreignField: "otherIds.orgId" // <field from the documents of the "from" collection>,
       as: "group-section" <output array field>
     }
}]);
```

Hope this give you idea.

Comment: I do not have mongo setup in current machine. But I tried all I think you put above code, it should work.